# Only keep this String in Notepad++ (Regex)

Tags: regex, editor, notepad++

I have again a Problem.
Have a list like

```
Ham$$Keepit=Keepit€ That was just Awesome #+üä!
Ber$$Dontremove=dontReMove€ delicious
```

Want to keep only between the $$ and €.
So the result should be

```
Keepit=Keepit
Dontremove=dontReMove
```

**Thanks for your help again !**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this(v5.9.3):

1. Open Replace dialog using Ctrl + H and make sure **Regular Expression** is checked in the **Search mode** panel.
2. Type `(.*)$$(.*)€(.*)` into the **Find what** textbox
3. Type `\2` into the **Replace with** textbox
4. Press **Replace All** and Voila!!! you will see the text you want.

Comment: For those wondering what this means: The paranthesis in the "Find what" field are capture groups, and the "\2" part means that the second capture group (second paranthesis) should replace the whole match.

Comment: Had to add \ to escape the dollars: `(.*)\$\$(.*)€(.*)`